# ActionMismatch while using web service

Tags: java, web-services

I'm trying to connect and use a web service method. I'm getting the following error:

```
The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'http://tempuri.org/xpto/foobar'.
```

In fact, the code says this:

```
_state.getMessageContext().setProperty("http.soap.action", "http://yadayadayada");
```

but it doesn't state anything about the message.

The WSDL states this:

```
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/foo/bar" message="tns:xpto"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been solved. I had to alter the code auto generated by WSDL2Java. 
In the Stub class, the auto generated code looks like this;

```
    (...)
           org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();
    _call.setOperation(_operations[11]);
    _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
    _call.setSOAPActionURI("http://tempuri.org/foo/bar");
    _call.setEncodingStyle(null);
    _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
    _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, Boolean.FALSE);
    _call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP12_CONSTANTS);
    _call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://tempuri.org/", "bar"));

    setRequestHeaders(_call);
    setAttachments(_call);
```

I had to add the following, before the setRequestHeaders:

```
    setHeader("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "To",  "http://WSDL.URL");
    setHeader("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "Action",  "http://tempuri.org/foo/bar");

    SOAPHeaderElement[]  headers = getHeaders();
    for (SOAPHeaderElement h : headers) { h.setRole(null); }

    setRequestHeaders(_call);
    setAttachments(_call);
```